# fadein each item (li) one after another using underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am displaying a list of items `<li>` from a JSON file using underscore, and instead of them all appearing at once, I'd like to fade them in one after another. How could I achieve this?

```
for (var j=0; j<rc.length; j++) {


%> 
<ul>
  <li class="productTile" data-id="<%= rc[j].id %>">
    <img src="<%= image %>" alt=""/>
    <h3>Demo<%= rc[j]["name"] %></h3>
    <p><%= rc[j].price.formatted %></p>
  </li>
</ul>

<%

                }  
                           };
%>
```

Comment: create entire list, each li element is display none, then step trough li elements and fade them in using jQuery

Comment: FadeIn is asynch. You must fade the next li element in the callback function of fadeIn.

Answer (score 0):

when cycling, to display your li elements one after another just set an increasing timeout:

```
var delay = 500;

for (var j=0; j<rc.length; j++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      //fadeIn my <li>
    }, delay*j)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create all div all at once with `display: none` style, then using a library [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) write something like:

```
// an array with all the ids
var ids = [...list of li ids...];

// handy async iterator
async.eachSeries(ids, fadeIdIterator, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Something gone wrong');
  }
});

// this function will do the job for each element
function fadeInIterator(id, next){
  $('#'+id).fadeIn('slow', next);
}
```

you can also write everything with jQuery but it's far more easily to write async stuff with this library.

Just to give an `underscore`-only alternative:

```
function fadeInIterator(id){
  return function(next) { $('#'+id).fadeIn('slow', next); };
}

// an array with all the ids
var ids = [...list of li ids...];

// this array will hold the callbacks
var fades = _.map(ids, function(id){  return fadeInIterator(id); });

_(fades).reduceRight(_.wrap, function() { console.warn('done') })();
```

For the `underscore` async alternative I've looked [here](http://daemon.co.za/2012/04/simple-async-with-only-underscore/)